# Android studio not showing exception Class and line numbers

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been using android studio for a while and whenever an exception occurs the information shown in the stacktrace does not contain the class in which the error occured or the line number. It is not even colored blue like it is supposed to. Here's an example of a stacktrace that is thrown:

```
ava.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=3
    at java.lang.String.indexAndLength(String.java:579)
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1438)
    at com.patriceandala.myapplication.utils.D.a(SourceFile:101)
    at com.patriceandala.myapplication.utils.D.a(SourceFile:29)
    at com.patriceandala.myapplication.utils.B.a(SourceFile:77)
    at d.b.a.a.run(SourceFile:46)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It only shows 'SourceFile' yet I don't have a class with that name. How can I fix this?

Comment: Probably it is from one of your **Library** that you used in your project

Comment: Are you using ProGuard in debug mode?

Comment: Yes, I am using proguard in debug mode

Comment: Don't use ProGuard in Debug mode, that's pointless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable **`ProGuard`** in debug mode and check.

Proguard is a free Java class file shrinker, optimizer, obfuscator and preverifier. It makes the code unreadable. So disable this in debug mode.